# React Hover to display information but hidden before hover

Tags: reactjs

This is my code so far

```
class PortfolioList extends Component{
render(){
    const {column , styevariation } = this.props;
    const list = PortfolioListContent.slice(0 , this.props.item);
    return(

        <React.Fragment>
            {list.map((value , index) => (

                <div className={`${column}`} key={index}>
                    <div className={`portfolio ${styevariation}`}>
                        <div className="thumbnail-inner">
                            <div className={`thumbnail ${value.image}`}></div>
                            <div className={`bg-blr-image ${value.image}`}></div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="content" >
                            <div className="inner">
                                <h3>{value.category}</h3>
                                <p><a href="/portfolio-details">{value.title}</a></p>
                                <div className="portfolio-button">
                                    <a className="rn-btn" href="/portfolio-details">Live</a>
                                </div>
                                <div className="portfolio-button">
                                    <a className="rn-btn" href="/portfolio-details">GitHub</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            ))}

        </React.Fragment>

    )
}
```

}

This is displaying my portfolio section of my website I want to display the title of the each application and details only when i want to hover.

Also How can i make my buttons wrap next to each other? instead of taking up the new line?
Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox link so I can properly tell you what you need to modify?

Answer (score 0):

You can use onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave event to handle hovering. Bind a function to this event on title and keep a local boolean state shouldShowDetails with default value false. When the function is called, change this boolean to true and conditionally render the details.

For the second part, make your buttons container a flex and set flex-wrap to wrap.

Comment: In this case i want the child elements of the div className of "inner" to be hidden until hover is active

do i bind the div with the classname of inner to the function?

Comment: Yes. You need to bind the function with inner class element. wrap the child elements so that you can conditionally render all of them using that boolean state.

Comment: can you show me an example of how to show details when hovered?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Here is a codesandbox link. You can get the idea from this. I've edited the answer a bit. Please have a look
https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-field-vvvcm?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Just use state instead of useState(). Rest will be the same. If you are asking me about syntax, you can find the class component syntax in react documentation